# Issues with httpd over 3G

Tags: iphone, linux, apache

I am experiencing a strange issue with connecting to my web server from my Iphone4.
I have an app that connects to my web serer and downloads a chunk of JSON.  This works fine when i'm connected via WIFI, but fails through 3G.  I don't think it's my app, as Safari also fails to retrieve any page on my web server when using 3G.
My web server has a fixed i.p and is running apache/Centos pretty fresh out of the box, I have not messed with the firewall or iptables settings.
The error obtained from the iphone is "The network connection was lost"
It feels like a firewall issue, but i have not explicitly denied any ips. Is there some aspect of a 3g connection that gets denied by default on Linux?
I realise this is all vague at this time, but does anyone have any wisdom to offer?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a topic](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=58545) related to iphone connection loss through 3G cellular data whereas WiFi works fine, also giving the error "The network connection was lost"

Answer (score 0):

Couple suggestions:

- Ensure that your web server is
  responding in a timely fashion.  If
  it is taking a little too much time,
  the 3g connection might give up.
- Check your web server logs and see if the connection is reaching
  your web server at all, and if any
  errors are being recorded.  If so,
  investigate.

There isn't anything special about a 3g connection wrt you web server.  Only difference would be that it is less reliable or slower.

Comment: I think it's a lower level problem.  The web server responds very quickly to all requests not made over 3G, from any network.  Also there is no entry in the httpd access logs for the failed 3G attempts. Thanks

Comment: You mention that you connect using the IP address of the machine.  Might I suggest you try connecting via a domain name.  (You can set up one with sites like dyndns.com).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have sorted out my dns now, and the issue is the same using the domain as well.  I'm beginning to think that it might be my mobile network, hosting provider, or somewhere in between at fault...i.e out of my control.

Answer (score 0):

How are you actually trying to connect to your web server? When its over wifi you are local on your network and the name of the server will probably work. But when its over 3g its on the interwebs and will probably not respond to the name of the server.

Comment: I connect using the i.p of the machine.  The wifi i connect thru is not local, its fine on wifi from any network in the city.

Comment: If i remember correctly (i can't check right now), there was no entry in the httpd access logs for the failed 3G attempts...implying a lower level issue.

Comment: heh, thats odd. Maybe carrier issue? Can you get to other servers using IP's, not domain names?